# Python makedirs permission denied

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an Apache httpd server running Python code using the Django framework and mod_wsgi. In my view.py I need to make a subprocess call to execute another Python file which in the process needs to create some directories.

However, I am getting `OSERROR 13: Permission denied` no matter where I try to create the directory.

Only creating a directory in `/tmp` is successful.

Can anyone guide me on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you check which user your scripts are running as and that that user has permission to write to the directories that you're adding files to ?

Answer (score 4):

Just a wild guess since I'm not a python dev myself, but your script is most likely running as the apache2 user (typically www-data on ubuntu/debian machines, you'll have to check on yours). If you make a directory writable for this user or group, you will be able to create the directory inside.

For example:

```
# creating the application dir
sudo mkdir /var/www/myapp

# creating the writable dir
sudo mkdir /var/www/myapp/writable

# change the group of this folder
sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/myapp/writable

# grant the group write access
sudo chmod g+w /var/www/myapp/writable
```